# Is it possible to build a django front end view with bootstrap only minus django views?

Tags: django, django-views

I want to build a django app minus using django views... Is it possible because I only want to concentrate on only bootstrap and python minus the django views.. And if I may get any added advantages of using views?!

Comment: The `views.py` is a central element of django. You should probably read into MVT (or [MVC](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/12/13/django-mvc-explanation.html)) patterns --> "The view layer is the user interface. Django splits this up in the actual HTML pages and the Python code (called views) that renders them." --> no views no template rendering

Answer (score 0):

yes and no... views are needed, but you can go to your template in one command using :

```
#urls.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^foo/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='foo.html')),
)
```